# (Alsamixer settings) Bluetooth microphone noisy sound

Tags: sound, alsa, microphone

I am new to Ubuntu. I have Ubuntu 20.10 installed on my Ausus. Yesterday I used my bluetooth JBL microphone for the the first time. It worked quite well, eventually I changed the settings on Alsamixer. I guess I messed up the right balance but I really do not know to restore them. I also installed QuasMixer but I have not clue which settings I should change.
I attached a series of screenshots to give you a general idea:

[image: QuasMixer]

[image: QuasMixer]

[image: QuasMixer]

[image: QuasMixer]

Please help me as I am a teacher, I definitively need to use a microphone to teach my online courses. Many thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for your reply. According to my settings/information I ha have Ubuntu 20.10 installed on my computer